# Customizing DocBook XSL NS section title styling

Tags: title, xsl-fo, docbook

I have "section.autolabel" set to 1 with a max.depth of 2. So, my section (sect1, sect2, sect3, ...) titles are as follows:

```
1. Introduction
1.1 All about it
1.2 Some more all abouts
```

These are generated as pure text (ie: "1.1 All about it") without any formatting specifically for the numbering and the title separately.

What I would like to do is separate the two components into two separate regions and keep the numbering far to the left and the title more right-ish, in line with the body text start indent. So something like this:

```
1.       Introduction

1.1      All about it.

         Yakkety smakkety with a blue blah blah. And then
         they lived happily ever after.

1.2      Some more all abouts 

         Etc.
```

I'm generating FO output and using the DocBook 5 + DocBook NS XSL with a rapidly growing customization layer.

So, I guess this question is two fold:

1. What can I override to have control of the title generation?  I'm a bit confused the flow inside fo/sections.xsl and how it fits together?
2. How would I introduce a fixed-width inline element to give the numbers and title their needed spacing?   I've been messing around with some fo:inline-containers, fo:block-containers but none of it is producing the result I want.

Comment: I'm not XSL-FO expert, but I think that the only way you could have a dynamic and consistence identation between both columns it should be a table...

Comment: @Alejandro: That's my impression too. I would be okay with using a table if the containers did not honour their width settings. I'm still a little clueless about #1, though.  I've given it a few days rest and I will tackle it again shortly.

Comment: I think the best approach will be to import DocBook XSLT into other stylesheet with a template matching nodes and attributes `node()|@*` and `xsl:apply-import` content template, and with another templates matching elements to transform into table layout (table, row, cell, etc.)